# Fault injection in the client libraries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I’m developing an app against Cloud Spanner, and since I’m a savvy programmer I want to test how my code behaves when Spanner starts returning ABORTs and other sorts of errors. Is there a way I can simulate this?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the official Cloud Spanner client libraries, they have various kinds of TransactionRunner abstractions that will retry on errors that we expect to be transient whilst bubbling up more severe problems. Using those is a good first step.